# Rotating polygon in geometry generator based on feature attribute?

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

That's a bounding box generated with the geometry generator with variables from a table:

```
geom_from_wkt( 
'POLYGON(('|| 
(x( $geometry ) + ("width"-"bleed")*"scale"/2)||' '||(y( $geometry ) + "height"*"scale"/2)||','||
(x( $geometry ) + ("width"-"bleed")*"scale"/2)||' '||(y( $geometry ) - "height"*"scale"/2)||','||
(x( $geometry ) - ("width"-"bleed")*"scale"/2)||' '||(y( $geometry ) - "height"*"scale"/2)||','||
(x( $geometry ) - ("width"-"bleed")*"scale"/2)||' '||(y( $geometry ) + "height"*"scale"/2)||','||
(x( $geometry ) + ("width"-"bleed")*"scale"/2)||' '||(y( $geometry ) + "height"*"scale"/2)||','||
'))')
```

Is it possible, to rotated such a geometry by value from attribute table?

[image]

Comment: I think you're going to need to use trigonometry. Try posting at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's very possible, but what's the attribute you're using to determine rotation? And do you want to rotate from centroid or vertex?

Comment: I want to rotate from centroid. The additional attribute for rotating could be the angle in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

This method has been tested and does NOT work in QGIS 2.18. Symbol rotation rotation applies only to simple markers, not to generated geometries.

---

Try adding data-defined rotation to the main symbol:
[image]

This method will rotate all symbol levels. To rotate only the geometry generator symbol, you'll need to duplicate the layer. Symbolize one copy of the layer with the rotated geometry generator symbol, and the other copy with the unrotated point marker.

Comment: Under 2.18.13, the generated geometries are not affected by this setting, only the simple markers.

Comment: I can confirm that. The rotation field is active, but have no effect (2.18.16)